# How can I delete rows from one table and insert into another using SQLAlchemy and Postgres RETURNING?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-returning, postgres-9.4

I would like to move rows from one table to another using SQLAlchemy with a Postgres database (there are other questions on Stack Overflow about moving data but they don't focus on using SQLAlchemy for this).

The approach is to use `DELETE` with `RETURNING` and to insert the rows into the other table.

I'm using: SQLAlchemy 1.0.12, Postgres 9.4 and Python 2.7.11.

### Setting up the tables

The following SQL creates the tables and inserts a row of data:

```sql
create table example1 (
    id integer,
    value_a integer,
    value_b integer,
    CONSTRAINT example1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
create table example2 (
    id integer,
    value_a integer,
    value_b integer,
    CONSTRAINT example2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into example1 values (18, 1, 9);
```

### Creating tables using SQLAlchemy

The following SQLAlchemy code creates the same tables and inserts a row of data:

```python
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ExampleOne(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example1'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value_a = Column(Integer)
    value_b = Column(Integer)


class ExampleTwo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example2'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value_a = Column(Integer)
    value_b = Column(Integer)


Base.metadata.create_all(session.bind)

with session.begin():
    session.add(ExampleOne(id=18, value_a=1, value_b=9))
```

### Query that I would like to implement

This is the SQL query that I wish to run (which works on its own):

```sql
with output as (delete from example1 where value_a < 10 returning id, value_a)
insert into example2 (id, value_a, value_b)
select id, value_a, 3 from output;
```

### SQLAlchemy query so far

The query that I have constructed so far is:

```python
query = insert(ExampleTwo, inline=True).from_select(
    ['id', 'value_a', 'value_b'],
    select(
        ['id', 'value_a', literal(3)]
    ).where(
        select([
            'id', 'value_a',
        ]).select_from(
            delete(ExampleOne).where(
                ExampleOne.value_a < 10,
            ).returning(
                ExampleOne.id,
                ExampleOne.value_a,
            )
        )
    )
)

session.execute(query)
```

### The problem

The error is:

```python
  File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 41, in _interpret_as_from
    raise exc.ArgumentError("FROM expression expected")
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: FROM expression expected
```

The problem seems to be that SQLAlchemy does not recognise the `DELETE ... RETURNING` query as a valid expression for the `FROM` part of the `INSERT` query.

Is there a way to make this clear to SQLAlchemy or is there are a different approach to create the given query in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `delete` expression into a CTE, as your raw SQL calls for:

```
>>> output = delete(ExampleOne).where(
...     ExampleOne.value_a < 10,
... ).returning(
...     ExampleOne.id,
...     ExampleOne.value_a,
... ).cte('output')
>>> query = insert(ExampleTwo, inline=True).from_select(
...     ['id', 'value_a', 'value_b'],
...     select(
...         ['id', 'value_a', literal(3)]
...     ).select_from(output)
... )
>>> query.compile(engine)
WITH output AS 
(DELETE FROM example1 WHERE example1.value_a < %(value_a_1)s RETURNING example1.id, example1.value_a)
 INSERT INTO example2 (id, value_a, value_b) SELECT id, value_a, %(param_1)s AS anon_1 
FROM output
```

Unfortunately, `.cte` only works on `delete` expressions in SQLAlchemy 1.1, which is currently unreleased, so you'll have to install SQLAlchemy from the source repo to make this work:

```
pip install -e git+https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy#egg=sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just tried it and it works. I'll add a note to the code and adapt the current query to the above when SQLAlchemy 1.1 is released.